# Twilio Conversations: How to create conversation with similar participants without running into 409?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086136/how-to-get-around-409-group-mms-with-given-participant-list-already-exists-as), I am attempting to do the following:

- I have a Twilio conversation `C1` with participants `P1`, `P2`
- I want to create a new conversation with participants `P1`, `P2`, `P3`

As soon as I add `P2` to the new convo, I will get the famous "Group MMS with given participant list already exists as Conversation" error and won't ever reach `P3`.

I know there is an accepted answer on the link I put, but this is not a scalable solution. Here's why:

I am building a solution where many conversations will be generated simultaneously due to user interactions with my applications. The accepted solution was to add `P4` first to the conversation and then remove `P4` after I add `P3` in order to have a unique conversation. Suppose however that multiple conversations are being generated simultaneously. If one has `P4` added already and is yet to attempt to add `P1`, then the second someone else tries to add the `P4` to the conversation, we would fail there.

Is there another solution to this problem that can actually scale? Would love if there was a way to add all the final participants at once and only then would Twilio check to see if a conversation exists with those participants.